# How to add Current Date and Time into Table?

Tags: javascript, function, datetime, html-table, datatable

how can I add the current date and time with this format: `2022-07-17 17:50:20`?

I already managed it with an input value but I need the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use built-in Date object in Javascript, like this:

```js
let currentdate = new Date(); 
let datetime = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-"
                + String((currentdate.getMonth() + 1)).padStart(2,"0")  + "-" 
                + String(currentdate.getDate()).padStart(2,"0") + " "
                + String(currentdate.getHours()).padStart(2,"0") + ":"  
                + String(currentdate.getMinutes()).padStart(2,"0") + ":" 
                + String(currentdate.getSeconds()).padStart(2,"0");
//The `+1` on the getMonth() is used because in Javascript January is 0.
console.log(datetime);
```

By the way, I suggest you make all your `var`s into `let`s as that's the current standard. There's a very fine difference between them (let is block scoped while var is functional scoped).

Comment: You have no idea how grateful I am to you right now! Thank you very much! but i have another question, the seconds format are now :1 .. :2.. how can i solve it to be .01 .. 02.. instead?

Comment: You're very much welcome. Just make sure to mark my answer as the answer to your question, so that other people don't waste their time on it.

Comment: I edited my comment, don't know if you were notified..

how can i make the seconds appear like this: ..01 .02 .03 and not like right now .1 .2 .3?

Comment: I have edited the code. Once it's accepted you can get the desire output. `String(n).padStart(2,'0')` for every `getMonth, getDate, getHours, getMinutes, getSeconds` because every digit will not be padded. If want urgently can add as an answer.

Comment: You can use `currentdate.getSeconds().toString().length === 1 ? "0" + currentdate.getSeconds().toString() : currentdate.getSeconds().toString()`, which is a sort way of writing `if(currentdate.getSeconds().toString().length === 1)` take the first option, which is `"0" + currentdate.getSeconds().toString()` and if not (which means the length has to be two characters) take the second option, which is `currentdate.getSeconds().toString()`.

Comment: I don't know how long it will take, so it would be good if you comment again :)

Again, thank you very very much! you helped me alot!

Comment: I'll try to look at the site every 10 minutes or so, to see if you need help. Anyway, I hope I helped you and wish you luck, and remember the mark the my answer as the answer.

Comment: edit is visible now @corpmeti you can check. @TheBooker66 aka Ethan  such check were done  before `padStart` was introduced

Comment: @GodWin, two things:
1. Thanks for introducing me to padStart. I wouldn't say I'm a novice js developer, but I'm not aware of all the intricacies of the language yet.
2. I don't have enough reputation to comment on the main post, but I agree with your comment on it.

Sorry for the edit, I accidentally pressed enter instead of ctrl+enter.

Comment: it works like charme now!! Thank you sooo much guys! @TheBooker66akaEthan & also @ GodWin

Comment: Good to hear and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can format ISO Date by JavaScript functions as follows:

```js
// Create element:
var todayDate = new Date().toISOString();
const dateField = document.createElement("p");
dateField.innerText = new Date().toISOString().split('.')[0].split('T').join(' ');

// Append to body:
document.body.appendChild(dateField);

// Output: 2022-07-17 16:31:22
```